# Subquery with multiple colums using count and sum and top

Tags: sql, subquery, temp-tables

Creating the following temp-table:

```
  CREATE TABLE #BEDRAGEN(Dossiercode T_Code_Dossier,Detailcode T_Code_Detail,DetailSubcode T_Code_DetailSub
                        ,Totaalbedrag T_Fin_Amount,TotGefactDiensten T_Fin_Amount, TotGefactgoederen T_Fin_Amount, Verzonden int
                        ,TotaalInkord T_Fin_Amount, TotaalInkRgls int,Inkooporder T_Nr_Ord, InkOrdRgl T_LineNR)

  INSERT INTO #BEDRAGEN
  SELECT DD.DossierCode as Dossiercode,
         DD.DetailCode as Detailcode,
         DD.DetailSubCode as DetailSubcode,
         ISNULL(DBO.SIF_get_SalesAmountDosDetail(DD.Dossiercode,DD.Detailcode,DD.Detailsubcode),0) as Totaalbedrag,
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ID.InvDetailAmount)
                FROM T_InvoiceDetailDosDet as IDD
                inner join T_InvoiceDetail as ID on ID.InvCode=IDD.InvCode and ID.InvLineNr=IDD.InvLinenr
                WHERE IDD.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND IDD.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND IDD.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubcode),0) 
                AS TotGefactDiensten,
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ID.InvDetailAmount)
                from T_InvoiceDetailShipDet as InvSD
                inner join T_ShippingDetail as SD on SD.ShipDocCode=InvSD.ShipDocCode and SD.ShipLineNr=InvSD.ShipLineNr
                inner join T_InvoiceDetail as ID on ID.InvCode=InvSD.InvCode and ID.InvLineNr=InvSD.InvLinenr
                where SD.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND SD.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND SD.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubcode),0) as TotGefactgoederen,
         ISNULL((select sum(Verz.DelQty) 
                from dbo.T_DeliveryLine as Verz
                where Verz.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode and Verz.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode and Verz.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubcode),0) as Verzonden,
         ISNULL((select sum(PDPL.BasicCurrTotalAmount) 
                from T_PurDocPartLineDosDetLink AS PDL
                INNER JOIN T_PurchaseDocument as PD on PDL.PurDocCode=PD.PurDocCode
                INNER JOIN T_PurDocPartLine as PDPL on PDPL.PurDocCode=PDL.PurDocCode and PDPL.PDPartLineNr=PDL.PDPartLineNr
                WHERE PDL.DossierCode=DD.DossierCode AND PDL.DetailCode=DD.DetailCode AND PDL.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubCode),0) AS TotaalInkord,
         ISNULL((select COUNT(PDL.DetailCode) 
                from T_PurDocPartLineDosDetLink AS PDL
                INNER JOIN T_PurchaseDocument as PD on PDL.PurDocCode=PD.PurDocCode
                INNER JOIN T_PurDocPartLine as PDPL on PDPL.PurDocCode=PDL.PurDocCode and PDPL.PDPartLineNr=PDL.PDPartLineNr
                WHERE PDL.DossierCode=DD.DossierCode AND PDL.DetailCode=DD.DetailCode AND PDL.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubCode),0) AS TotaalInkRgls,
         ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 PD.PurOrdNr FROM T_PurDocPartLineDosDetLink AS PDL 
                INNER JOIN T_PurchaseDocument as PD on PDL.PurDocCode=PD.PurDocCode
                INNER JOIN T_PurDocPartLine AS INR ON INR.PurDocCode=PDL.PurDocCode AND INR.PDPartLineNr=PDL.PDPartLineNr
                WHERE  PDL.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND PDL.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND PDL.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubCode),'') AS Inkooporder,
        ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 PDL.PDPartLineNr FROM T_PurDocPartLineDosDetLink AS PDL 
                INNER JOIN T_PurchaseDocument as PD on PDL.PurDocCode=PD.PurDocCode
                INNER JOIN T_PurDocPartLine AS INR ON INR.PurDocCode=PDL.PurDocCode AND INR.PDPartLineNr=PDL.PDPartLineNr
                WHERE  PDL.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND PDL.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND PDL.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubCode),0) AS InkOrdRgl
  FROM dbo.T_DossierDetail AS DD
  Inner Join    dbo.T_Part  AS P On P.PartCode = DD.PartCode
  Inner Join    dbo.T_DossierMain  AS DM On DM.DossierCode = DD.DossierCode
  Inner Join    dbo.T_DossierStatus  AS DS On DS.DossierStatusCode = DD.DossierStatusCode
  WHERE    DD.DossierCode > N''

 select * from #bedragen

 drop table #BEDRAGEN
```

As you can see the subqueries to get the columns TotaalInkord,TotaalInkRgls,Inkooporder,InkOrdRgl 
are using the same from/innerjoin and where.

Is there a possibility to combine these?
If combining is possible will it be faster?

Thank you

Background: 
I need this temp-table to speed up performance on a stored procedure. 
This stored procedure is a large select using a number of functions to obtain its colums.
This function-content I have now added in the temptable.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sql server.. i guess..

Comment: yes it is sql server

Comment: 2012 te be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO #BEDRAGEN
      SELECT DD.DossierCode as Dossiercode,
             DD.DetailCode as Detailcode,
             DD.DetailSubCode as DetailSubcode,
             ISNULL(DBO.SIF_get_SalesAmountDosDetail(DD.Dossiercode,DD.Detailcode,DD.Detailsubcode),0) as Totaalbedrag,
             ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ID.InvDetailAmount)
                    FROM T_InvoiceDetailDosDet as IDD
                    inner join T_InvoiceDetail as ID on ID.InvCode=IDD.InvCode and ID.InvLineNr=IDD.InvLinenr
                    WHERE IDD.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND IDD.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND IDD.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubcode),0) 
                    AS TotGefactDiensten,
             ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ID.InvDetailAmount)
                    from T_InvoiceDetailShipDet as InvSD
                    inner join T_ShippingDetail as SD on SD.ShipDocCode=InvSD.ShipDocCode and SD.ShipLineNr=InvSD.ShipLineNr
                    inner join T_InvoiceDetail as ID on ID.InvCode=InvSD.InvCode and ID.InvLineNr=InvSD.InvLinenr
                    where SD.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND SD.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND SD.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubcode),0) as TotGefactgoederen,
             ISNULL((select sum(Verz.DelQty) 
                    from dbo.T_DeliveryLine as Verz
                    where Verz.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode and Verz.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode and Verz.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubcode),0) as Verzonden,
             ISNULL(IO.waarde,0) as TotaalInkord,
             ISNULL(IO.rgls,0) as TotaalInkRgls,
             ISNULL(IO.PurOrdNr,'') as Inkooporder,
             ISNULL(IO.PDPartLineNr,'') as InkOrdRgl
      FROM dbo.T_DossierDetail AS DD
      Inner Join    dbo.T_Part  AS P On P.PartCode = DD.PartCode
      Inner Join    dbo.T_DossierMain  AS DM On DM.DossierCode = DD.DossierCode
      Inner Join    dbo.T_DossierStatus  AS DS On DS.DossierStatusCode = DD.DossierStatusCode
      Inner Join    #StatusType ST on DS.DossierStatusType = ST.StatusType
      OUTER APPLY (SELECT top 1 PD.PurOrdNr,PDL.PDPartLineNr,COUNT(PDL.DetailCode) as rgls,sum(PDPL.BasicCurrTotalAmount) as waarde 
                    FROM T_PurDocPartLineDosDetLink AS PDL 
                    INNER JOIN T_PurchaseDocument as PD on PDL.PurDocCode=PD.PurDocCode
                    INNER JOIN T_PurDocPartLine AS PDPL ON PDPL.PurDocCode=PDL.PurDocCode AND PDPL.PDPartLineNr=PDL.PDPartLineNr
                    WHERE  PDL.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND PDL.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND PDL.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubCode
                    GROUP BY PD.PurOrdNr,PDL.PDPartLineNr,PDL.DetailCode,PDPL.BasicCurrTotalAmount)  IO
      WHERE    DD.DossierCode > N''
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult without sample data, but a CROSS APPLY should do the trick - couldn't say if it would perform better (it should though) and you might have to tweak this a bit.

```
CREATE TABLE #BEDRAGEN(Dossiercode T_Code_Dossier,Detailcode T_Code_Detail,DetailSubcode T_Code_DetailSub
                        ,Totaalbedrag T_Fin_Amount,TotGefactDiensten T_Fin_Amount, TotGefactgoederen T_Fin_Amount, Verzonden int
                        ,TotaalInkord T_Fin_Amount, TotaalInkRgls int,Inkooporder T_Nr_Ord, InkOrdRgl T_LineNR)

  INSERT INTO #BEDRAGEN
  SELECT DD.DossierCode as Dossiercode,
         DD.DetailCode as Detailcode,
         DD.DetailSubCode as DetailSubcode,
         ISNULL(DBO.SIF_get_SalesAmountDosDetail(DD.Dossiercode,DD.Detailcode,DD.Detailsubcode),0) as Totaalbedrag,
         sub.TotGefactDiensten,
         sub.TotGefactgoederen,
         sub.Verzonden,
         sub.TotaalInkord,
         sub.TotaalInkRgls,
         sub.Inkooporder,
         sub.InkOrdRgl
  FROM dbo.T_DossierDetail AS DD
  Inner Join    dbo.T_Part  AS P On P.PartCode = DD.PartCode
  Inner Join    dbo.T_DossierMain  AS DM On DM.DossierCode = DD.DossierCode
  Inner Join    dbo.T_DossierStatus  AS DS On DS.DossierStatusCode = DD.DossierStatusCode
  cross apply (
        SELECT 
            ISNULL(SUM(ID.InvDetailAmount), 0) as TotGefactDiensten
            ISNULL(SUM(ID.InvDetailAmount), 0) as as TotGefactgoederen
            ISNULL(sum(Verz.DelQty) ,0) as Verzonden,
            ISNULL(sum(PDPL.BasicCurrTotalAmount) ,0) AS TotaalInkord,
            ISNULL(COUNT(PDL.DetailCode) ,0) AS TotaalInkRgls,
            ISNULL(min(PD.PurOrdNr), '') AS Inkooporder,  -- assuming this PD.PurOrdNr is the same for all records of subquery ???
            ISNULL(min(PDL.PDPartLineNr),0) AS InkOrdRgl
        FROM T_PurDocPartLineDosDetLink AS PDL 
        INNER JOIN T_PurchaseDocument as PD on PDL.PurDocCode=PD.PurDocCode
        INNER JOIN T_PurDocPartLine AS INR ON INR.PurDocCode=PDL.PurDocCode AND INR.PDPartLineNr=PDL.PDPartLineNr
        WHERE  PDL.DossierCode=DD.Dossiercode AND PDL.DetailCode=DD.Detailcode AND PDL.DetailSubCode=DD.DetailSubCode
    ) sub

WHERE    DD.DossierCode > N''

 select * from #bedragen

 drop table #BEDRAGEN
```

Comment: Thx. I tried the outerapply (see code in answer) what is the difference with cross apply?

Comment: -- assuming this PD.PurOrdNr is the same for all records of subquery ???

It does not need to be. Most of the time it will. But there can also be 2 or 3, and it needs to display only the first. Hence my TOP 1

Comment: Cross Apply is usually quicker.

APPLY causes the right-side query to execute once per result in the left-side query. CROSS only considers matching rows like INNER JOIN. Using OUTER considers all rows in left-side query.

However, when all the columns in the right side are aggregated, the cross apply also acts like an outer join - you don't "loose" the entire row when not matched.